# PHP Output to variable

Tags: php, html

File-1:

```
<?php
  <div>
    <p>
      something...
    </p>
   </div>
?>
```

File-2:

```
<?php
   $file1= What should I write to get output of File1?
?>
```

I need to get html output to the $file1 variable;
Please help.

Comment: Your first file would not run for sure... Please clarify: is your File-1 a PHP file that you want to execute and grab its output, or is it an HTML file that you just want to read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
function read($file) {
  ob_start();
  include($file);
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  return $content;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$file = 'path/to/your/file.php';
$content = read($file);
```

To pass variables you can modify function above like this:

```
  function read($file, $vars) {
    ob_start();
    extract($vars, EXTR_SKIP);
    include($file);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $content;
  }

  $file = 'path/to/your/file.php';
  $vars = array(
    'var1' => 'value',
  );
  $content = read($file, $vars);
```

You can access variables in included file like this: print $var1;

Comment: Thank you. It is working. If you would allow me I would add 1 question to you. If I want to send a variable to file-1 as like $_GET or $_POST then what should I do?

Comment: but what would be in file-1 to get vars? will it $getVer = $var1; or $getVar = $vars...

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
```

to start output buffering, then include your file and use

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php
```

to read what was the output and finish with

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php
```

to end the buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is this you are looking for:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php

Visit the section:
PHP - File Read: fread Function

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
   $content = file_get_contents('somefile.txt');
```

Comment: but he has php in that file, what he wants is the output of that file and not the file content itself.

Comment: he can call it through url e.g file_get_contents('http://localhost/file1.php'), in this way he can get the html content.

Answer (score 0):

You could either set the variable in `File-1` and include it:

`include()` / `include_once()` / `require()` / `require_once()`

Or you could print the contents of `File-1` and use `output buffering`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php